# SOAP Client PHP Error: SOAP-ENV:Server; Procedure 'functionName' not present

Tags: php, web-services, wsdl, soap-client, nusoap

i'm using a PHP client for consume a testing web service, I've written my code with the native PHP Soap client and with nusoap library, but get same error.

The response of operation is:

> [faultcode] => SOAP-ENV:Server
>
> [faultstring] => Procedure 'xxx' not present

If i use the $client->__getFunctions()  it shows correctly the functions, but i don't understand the fault, in many sites recommends disable WSDL caching, but still failing with this changes.

WSDL File used, PHP code for webservice and images folder:
https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BxjxYDI011PdNzBBYlBza1VBY0E

List of functions response (no libraries):
Image name: native.png

Nusoap response (calling function):
Image name: response.png

Additionally i test that with SoapUI but get same response with this status: HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Service Error

I test that client with this webservice with no problems:
http://www.xignite.com/xquotes.asmx?WSDL
Then the code seems to be correct, but...

I need to know if my code has an error, the wsdl definition(i don't any access to server, only this file), or something else, I appreciate any information.

Answer (score 0):

In response.png for your Request, your SOAPAction should point to 'getBankList', not 'http://...' (which points to the service).  I'm not sure where you are setting this in the code, but the SOAPAction should point to the wsdl:service name="" value, not the actual running service.

Also, looking at the xignite WSDL, it doesn't have a getBankList function, or in fact the word 'Bank' in it at all.  Are you sure you're pointing to the correct WSDL?

HTH, Jim